# Count how many cases exist per week given start and end dates of each case

Tags: r

I'm new here, so I apologize if I miss any conventions.

I have a ~2000 row dataset with data on unique cases happening in a three year period. Each case has a start date and an end date. I want to be able to get a new dataframe that shows how many cases occur per week in this three year period.

The structure of the dataset I have is like this:

```
ID  Start_Date  End_Date      
1   2015-01-04  2017-11-02    
2   2015-01-05  2015-10-26    
3   2015-01-07  2015-03-04     
4   2015-01-12  2016-05-17  
5   2015-01-15  2015-04-08
6   2015-01-21  2016-07-31 
7   2015-01-21  2015-07-16
8   2015-01-22  2015-03-03
```

`

Comment: You need to state how much of each week needs to contain a case for it to be counted in that week.

Comment: To get a better answer, we'd like you to show some "research effort" when posting a question on StackOverflow. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think, if you want to make it easy for people to give you an answer, you could include code that produces a test data frame and another that produces a list of all the weeks: start date and end date.

Comment: Need to distinguish whether you want the number of new cases in a week of the total number prevalent during that week. So si guess closing is the right move, but do read all of the comments and use [edit] features to improve your question (after making good faith effort to search for earlier answers which I suspect exist.)

Comment: @42- I agree. The desired output is not very clear from OP. OP had broadly mention about a column of number of cases in each week over period of 3 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved more easily with `sqldf` package but I thought to stick with `dplyr` package.

The approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# First create a data frame having all weeks from chosen start date to end date. 
# 2015-01-01 to 2017-12-31
df_week <- data.frame(weekStart = seq(floor_date(as.Date("2015-01-01"), "week"),
                                     as.Date("2017-12-31"), by = 7))
df_week <- df_week %>% 
  mutate(weekEnd = weekStart + 7,
                   weekNum = as.character(weekStart, "%V-%Y"), 
                   dummy = TRUE)
# The dummy column is only for joining purpose. 
# Header looks like
#> head(df_week)
#   weekStart    weekEnd weekNum dummy
#1 2014-12-28 2015-01-04 52-2014  TRUE
#2 2015-01-04 2015-01-11 01-2015  TRUE
#3 2015-01-11 2015-01-18 02-2015  TRUE
#4 2015-01-18 2015-01-25 03-2015  TRUE
#5 2015-01-25 2015-02-01 04-2015  TRUE
#6 2015-02-01 2015-02-08 05-2015  TRUE

# Prepare the data as mentioned in OP
df <- read.table(text = "ID  Start_Date  End_Date      
1   2015-01-04  2017-11-02    
2   2015-01-05  2015-10-26    
3   2015-01-07  2015-03-04     
4   2015-01-12  2016-05-17  
5   2015-01-15  2015-04-08
6   2015-01-21  2016-07-31 
7   2015-01-21  2015-07-16
8   2015-01-22  2015-03-03", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$Start_Date <- as.Date(df$Start_Date)
df$End_Date <- as.Date(df$End_Date)
df <- df %>% mutate(dummy = TRUE)     # just for joining

# Use dplyr to join, filter and then group on week to find number of cases
# in each week
df_week %>%
  left_join(df, by = "dummy") %>%
  select(-dummy) %>%
  filter((weekStart >= Start_Date & weekStart <= End_Date) | 
           (weekEnd >= Start_Date & weekEnd <= End_Date)) %>%
  group_by(weekStart, weekEnd, weekNum) %>%
  summarise(cases = n())

# Result
#   weekStart  weekEnd    weekNum cases
#   <date>     <date>     <chr>   <int>
# 1 2014-12-28 2015-01-04 52-2014     1
# 2 2015-01-04 2015-01-11 01-2015     3
# 3 2015-01-11 2015-01-18 02-2015     5
# 4 2015-01-18 2015-01-25 03-2015     8
# 5 2015-01-25 2015-02-01 04-2015     8
# 6 2015-02-01 2015-02-08 05-2015     8
# 7 2015-02-08 2015-02-15 06-2015     8
# 8 2015-02-15 2015-02-22 07-2015     8
# 9 2015-02-22 2015-03-01 08-2015     8
#10 2015-03-01 2015-03-08 09-2015     8
# ... with 139 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Before solving the problem be sure to have installed some packages and run

```
install.packages(c("tidyr","dplyr","lubridate"))
```

if you haven installed those packages yet.

I'll present you a modern R solution next and those packages are magic.

This is a way to solve it:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

raw_data <- 'id start_date  end_date
1   2015-01-04  2017-11-02
2   2015-01-05  2015-10-26
3   2015-01-07  2015-03-04
4   2015-01-12  2016-05-17
5   2015-01-15  2015-04-08
6   2015-01-21  2016-07-31
7   2015-01-21  2015-07-16
8   2015-01-22  2015-03-03'

curated_data <- read_delim(raw_data, delim = "\t") %>% 
  mutate(start_date = as.Date(start_date)) %>% # convert column 2 to date format assuming the date is yyyy-mm-dd
  mutate(weeks_lapse = as.integer((start_date - min(start_date))/dweeks(1))) # count how many weeks passed since the lowest date in the data

curated_data %>% 
  group_by(weeks_lapse) %>%  # I group to count by week
  summarise(cases_per_week = n()) # now count by group by week
```

And the solution is:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  weeks_lapse cases_per_week
        <int>          <int>
1           0              3
2           1              2
3           2              3
```

Comment: I'm not sure if result is desired output. In fact, I cannot understand result.

Comment: What I am doing is starting from a "zero" arbitrary value. Let's say 2015-01-04 is a date contained in the first week of January, so that week is week 0 arbitrarily. Then suppose I have a date 2015-01-07 and that belongs to week 1. Try to count cases in weeks 0,1,...,n by hand following that logic and you should obtain the same results as above.